# Accessing command line arguments from Spring Beans (in this case, ApplicationReadyEvent listener)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have a Spring-Boot application which we start by passing some arguments via the command line.

We want to access these arguments when we receive an ApplicationReadyEvent, to execute some logic at application startup.

I am not able to get that working. Tried with @EventListener annotation and even interface but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're just asking how you can get access to the application's command line arguments inside of an event listener.  To do that, you can just inject the `ApplicationArguments` bean into your listener object, via its constructor, like so:

```
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Component
public class Ready implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    private ApplicationArguments appArgs;

    public Ready(ApplicationArguments appArgs) {
        this.appArgs = appArgs;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {
        System.out.println("App Args: " + Arrays.asList(appArgs.getSourceArgs()));
    }
}
```

Once you have the `ApplicationArguments` object, you can access the command line arguments as an array via the `getSourceArgs()` method.  I turn the array into a list just so it will print correctly.

As a test, I passed the three arguments 'a', 'b' and 'c' to my app at startup, and this line is printed at the end of app startup:

```
App Args: [a, b, c]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I did it a hard way by making a dummy entry in application.properties and in the main class overriding the default properties by application object.

But the above one looks lot cleaner. Will i be able to access this anywhere in the application using the @Autowired annotation?

Comment: Yes.  This mechanism has nothing to do with the event listener specifically.  You can do this with any Bean, injecting via either constructor params or @Autowired.  In fact, I wrote it as \@Autowired first, but I've been encouraging people to use constructor injection instead, so I changed it to use constructor injection.  Works either way.